# IOError: [Errno 0] Error while scrolling in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from urllib2 import Request
import urllib

values = raw_input("keyword : ")
params = urllib.pathname2url(values)
url = "https://search.naver.com/search.naver? 
where=nexearch&sm=top_hty&fbm=0&ie=utf8&query=" + params
print(url)

data = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
print(data)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPHHM.jpg)

This is my code and I got this Error. I have no idea to solve this...

Comment: Is there really a linebreak in your string literal? Oh, and please replace the raw input with a fixed value, to rule out any ambiguous interpretation  of your [mcve].

Comment: The traceback says the error occurs in `print(data)`. Why not just leave that out and move on with your actual task?